# Why computation of $u*v^3*(u*v^7)^{(p-5)/8}$ is suggested instead of $(u/v)^{(p+3)/8}$

Tags: elliptic-curves, algorithm-design, modular-arithmetic, ed25519, x25519

Working with Curve25519 I've faced with suggested form of computation square root candidate as: $uv^3(uv^7)^{\frac{p-5}{8}}$ instead of $\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{\frac{p+3}{8}}$. Why it is so? Or why is it less expensive?

- Edwards-Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (EdDSA) https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-5.1.3
- High-speed high-security signatures https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/368.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{7(p-5)}8+3=\frac{7p-11}8\equiv \frac{7p-11}8-p-1\equiv -\frac{(p+3)}8\pmod{p-1}.$$

Similarly
$$\frac{p-5}8+1=\frac{p+3}8$$

And so $v^3(v^7)^{\frac{p-5}8}\equiv v^{-\frac{(p+3)}8}\pmod p$.

Likewise $u(u)^{\frac{p-5}8}\equiv u^{\frac{p+3}8}$ as required.

The reason is to save a modular division which is quite a pricey operation.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why LaTeX formatting might be on the fritz?

Comment: You have a misplaced }

Comment: Do I understand correctly that modular division is most expensive operation in this calculations?

Comment: @mahnunchik Depending on what you count as an operation, but yes. A modular exponentiation probably costs a little more, but appears in both formulae and can't really be avoided.